# const reference must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, initialization

I am trying to block access to the default constructor of a class I am writing.  The constructor I want others to use requires a const reference to another object.  I have made the default constructor private to prevent others from using it.  I am getting a compiler error for the default constructor because the const reference member variable is not initialized properly.  What can I do to make this compile?

```
class CFoo
{
public:
    CFoo();
    ~CFoo();
};

class CBar
{
public:
    CBar(const CFoo& foo) : fooReference(foo)
    {
    }

    ~CBar();

private:
    const CFoo& fooReference;

    CBar() // I am getting a compiler error because I don't know what to do with fooReference here...
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

don`t declare default constructor.
It is not available anyway (automatically that it's) if you declare your own constructor.

```
class CBar
{
public:
    CBar(const CFoo& foo) : fooReference(foo)
    {
    }
private:
    const CFoo& fooReference;
};
```

fairly comprehensive explanation of constructors can be found here:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html

Comment: Thank you for the help.  For some reason, I thought the compiler generated a default constructor even if I did not write one.

Comment: @Trevor It does, provided you don't explicitly declare a constructor (of any kind) in your class definition.

Comment: @Trevor You may also need to block the copy constructor as well.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to create the default constructor you don't wanna use (that is the case with your constructor, is that right?) is just not defining it, that is:

```
class CBar
{
public:
    CBar(const CFoo& foo) : fooReference(foo)
    {
    }

    ~CBar();

private:
    const CFoo& fooReference;

    CBar();
};
```

In this case, it may be a little superfluous, because the compiler will not create a default constructor for a class with a reference member, but it's better to put it there in case you delete the reference member.